# IIS redirect for https

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

I'm using the URL rewrite module from IIS

It is working fine for https redirect
e.g. http://some.site.com  --> https://some.site.com

The subdomain changed so I adjusted the rule
http://some.site.com  --> https://some2.site.com
This works fine

Challenge is to change https access
https://some.site.com  --> https://some2.site.com

As the certificate SAN is set to some2.site.com all browsers
first display a certificate warning when accessing https://some.site.com
After confirming that the redirect is done. I tried both URL rewrite on root level and on web site level (Default Web Site) with no noticable effect.
Failed request tracing did not log anything.

How to redirect from
https://some.site.com to https://some2.site.com
without warning?

Comment: What are the DNS names configured in the SAN cert? Note that for HTTPS redirection, both domain names must present with valid certs, as there are two HTTPS connections.

Comment: @Lex Li SAN is only for some2.site.com as some.site.com (used as a place holder here) was a soon to become invalid name containing underscore. If the SAN contained both names the redirect would work without warning